# Using arguments to send emoji discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello im trying to send emoji using args.
This is code I have so far

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if (command === 'f') {
        if (args[0] === 'agrona') {
            return message.channel.send(':agrona:970341615715627079');
        } else if (args[1] === 'aurora') {
            return message.channel.send(":Aurora:970341793042403449");
        } else if (args[2] === 'elizabeth') {
            return message.channel.send(":elizabeth:970341810469752862");
        } else if (args[3] === 'icy') {
            return message.channel.send(":icy:970341824633929728");
        } else if (args[4] === 'issa') {
            return message.channel.send(":issa:970341862680440882");
        }
        
        message.channel.send(`${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} ${args[3]} ${args[4]}`);
    }
});
```

I event tried to define it like this but it didnt work:

```
if (command === 'f') {
        if (args[0] === 'agrona') {
        const Emoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'agrona');
            return message.channel.send(`${Emoji});
```

But all I got was undefined response from bot.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use like that: `<:agrona:970341615715627079>`, make sure your bot is on the server where the exact emoji is

Comment: I tried even that. still didnt work. response is just :agrona:

Comment: did you create the emoji with that name?

Comment: Yes I have that emoji uploaded to my server where bot is located.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: The way @JustRoman said you should do it is the correct way to do it. If that isn't working for you, check that your bot has permissions to use custom emoji in the server and in the channel you are sending in.

Comment: My bot have Admin permissions. Is there anything else that could cause troubles?

Comment: Try client.emojis.cache.find instead, that works for me.

Comment: I got emoji to be shown now. But the problem is that only args[0] emoji is shown and not all. I use command like this ``$f agrona aurora elizabeth icy issa``  but from that command nothing after agrona is shown.

Comment: Well you're using `if` and `else if` statements @MarioGrđan. If one of those statements run, the rest won't. If you want all of them to be able to run from the same command, you need to change all of the `else if` statements into `if` statements, and you also need to remove the `return` keyword from each of the `if` blocks.

Comment: I figured this out thanks for help everyone